# click on a tab inside ts file

Tags: angular, protractor, ionic2

I am performing an e2e testing, Here i need to open the tabs which are not present in html file it is located in ts file as a template

```
import {soPage}                 from    './soList.ts';
import {poPage}                 from    './poList.ts';

@Page({

    template : 
        `<ion-tabs primary  class="tabs" id="tabs" selectedIndex="1">
            <ion-tab [root]="tab1" class="tab1"  tabTitle="SO" ></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab [root]="tab2"  class="tab2"  tabTitle="PO" ></ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>`,

})
```

i tried in e2e as:

```
describe('Approval Module', () => {
    it('Should click on the SO tab',() => {
        element(by.css(tab1)).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(6000); 
    });
});
```

but i got an err like

```
approval.e2e.ts (3,18): Cannot find name 'tab1'. (2304)
```

could some one help me to click that tab

Answer (score 2):

You used tab1 as an variable, but it should be a string. Change this line

```
element(by.css(tab1)).click();
```

to

```
element(by.css('tab1')).click();
```

And this error should be fixed.

Comment: still i get the same err "- Failed: element not visible"

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan I will not be able to help you here, because I have no experience with protractor and iconic2, sorry

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan that's a separate problem and there could be different reasons for it. Please create a separate question if you experience difficulties solving it and need help. Thanks.